# What is the DC of the Tempest Cleric's Wrath of the Storm feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, saving-throw, difficulty-class

[Tempest Domain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#TempestDomain) clerics have the ability [Wrath of the Storm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#WrathoftheStorm-149) (PHB, p. 62):

> When a creature within 5 feet of you that you can see hits you with an attack, you can use your reaction to cause the creature to **make a Dexterity saving throw.** The creature takes 2d8 lightning or thunder damage (your choice) on a failed saving throw, and half as much damage on a successful one.

It doesn't specify what the DC of the saving throw is.

I assume it uses the spell save DC, even though it technically isn't a spell?

> Spell save DC = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Wisdom modifier

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Cleric's Spell Save DC

You are correct that RAW the saving DC is not specified. I have been unable to find any source that officially corrects this oversight. However, I think using the cleric's spell save DC is a fairly safe assumption.

Most cleric features that require a save come under the *Channel Divinity* set of features. In the text for that feature we have:

> Some Channel Divinity effects require saving throws. When you use such an effect from this class, the DC equals your cleric spell save DC.

Technically *Wrath of the Storm* is neither a spell nor a *Channel Divinity* effect so this isn't RAW. I believe we can draw an effective parallel to use this a precedent though. Additionally, [wisdom is listed as the primary ability for clerics](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#ClassesSummary) so it is a reasonable assumption to default to this when a class feature is lacking an exact definition.

Comment: Dndbeyond's character builder seems to agree with our assumptions. The text doesn't explain how it's calculated, but it looks like 8+prof+wis.