# Can a multiclassed Sorcerer/Tempest Cleric use Charisma instead of Wisdom to determine save DC for the Wrath of the Storm feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, sorcerer, difficulty-class

I have a question related to this one:
[What is the DC of the Tempest Cleric's Wrath of the Storm feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154737/what-is-the-dc-of-the-tempest-clerics-wrath-of-the-storm-feature)

Since the rules don't specify how you calculate your DC for this ability, could a multiclass Sorcerer/Cleric use their Charisma instead of their Wisdom modifier?

Comment: Since the linked question is about D&D 5e, I've added the appropriate tag to your question as well.

Comment: Given that the accepted answer to the linked question is "RAW the DC is not specified", what are you expecting from this question?

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the Spell Save DC(s) of a multiclassed character?

Comment: If the question is "how to calculate the DC specifically for a multiclass character" then it is not a duplicate of the linked question. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132854/can-a-multiclass-character-use-either-of-its-spellcasting-modifiers-for-spells might be more relevant.